# Spring Boot Test - Async method in test suite does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

I'm writing a test class and I want to verify that a method annotated with **Async** and returning a **CompletableFuture** executes a branch of code

## WHAT IS USE

1. Spring Boot 3.x
2. Mockito
3. Spring Test
4. Spring Async
5. Spring Integration (JMS)
6. VSCode

## WHAT I DEVELOPED

I have developed this Java Class **ClientTracingServiceImpl**:

```java
package com.tutorial.experiment.service.tracing;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.tutorial.experiment.component.mapper.IClientTracingMapper;
import com.tutorial.experiment.data.interfaces.TracingMessage;
import com.tutorial.experiment.data.types.ClientTracing;
import com.tutorial.experiment.data.types.EErrorCodes;
import com.tutorial.experiment.data.types.EMessageTopology;
import com.tutorial.experiment.data.types.EStep;
import com.tutorial.experiment.database.db2.entity.tracing.ClientTracingEntity;
import com.tutorial.experiment.database.db2.repository.tracing.IClientTracingRepository;
import com.tutorial.experiment.exception.common.SystemApplicationException;
import com.tutorial.experiment.exception.tracing.ClientTracingNotFoundException;
import com.tutorial.experiment.exception.tracing.InvalidTracingMessageTypeException;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Service
public class ClientTracingServiceImpl implements IClientTracingService {

    private final IClientTracingRepository repository;
    private final IClientTracingMapper mapper;
    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    @Async("jmsThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<Void> notifyTracing(TracingMessage message) throws InvalidTracingMessageTypeException {
        String destinationName = "";
        EMessageTopology type = message.getType();
        if (type == null) {
            throw new InvalidTracingMessageTypeException();
        }
        destinationName = switch (type) {
            case REQUEST -> "tracing.client.request";
            case RESPONSE -> "tracing.client.response";
            default -> throw new InvalidTracingMessageTypeException();
        };
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationName, message);
        log.info("Notified message: '{}'", message);
        return new CompletableFuture<>();
    }
    
    @Timed(value = "find.tracing.by.id.timer", description = "Time of execution of the search a specific tracing by id")
    @Override
    public ClientTracing findTracingById(Long idTracing, String xRequestId)
            throws ClientTracingNotFoundException, SystemApplicationException {
        ClientTracing response = null;
        try {
            ClientTracingEntity queryResult = repository.findById(idTracing)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new ClientTracingNotFoundException(idTracing));
            response = mapper.entityToData(queryResult);
        } catch (ClientTracingNotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SystemApplicationException(
                    "Occurred an internal error while search tracing with id: " + idTracing, e,
                    EErrorCodes.ENTITY_SEARCH, EStep.FIND_TRACE);
        }
        log.info("Record found with id: '{}'", idTracing);
        return response;
    }
    
    @Timed(value = "find.tracing.timer", description = "Time of execution of the search a specific tracing")
    @Override
    public List<ClientTracing> findTracing(String xRequestId, String requestId, String responseId)
            throws ClientTracingNotFoundException, SystemApplicationException {
        List<ClientTracing> response = null;
        try {
            ClientTracingEntity entity = ClientTracingEntity.builder().requestId(requestId).responseId(responseId)
                    .build();
            List<ClientTracingEntity> queryResult = repository.findAll(Example.of(entity));
            if (queryResult.isEmpty()) {
                throw new ClientTracingNotFoundException(requestId, responseId);
            }
            response = queryResult.stream()
                    .map(mapper::entityToData)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (ClientTracingNotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SystemApplicationException(
                    "Occurred an internal error while search tracing with requestId: " + requestId + " and responseId: "
                            + responseId,
                    EErrorCodes.ENTITY_SEARCH, EStep.MAPPING_TRACE_RESPONSE);
        }
        return response;
    }

}
```

## WHAT I WANT TO DO

1. Test all positive scenarios of the **notifyMethod** in async mode
2. Test all negative scenarios of the **notifyMethod** with cautch exception in async mode

This is my test class **ClientTracingServiceImplTest**:

```java
package com.tutorial.experiment.service.tracing;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.tutorial.experiment.data.interfaces.TracingMessage;
import com.tutorial.experiment.data.types.EErrorCodes;
import com.tutorial.experiment.data.types.EMessageTopology;
import com.tutorial.experiment.data.types.EStep;
import com.tutorial.experiment.database.db2.repository.tracing.IClientTracingRepository;
import com.tutorial.experiment.exception.tracing.InvalidTracingMessageTypeException;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpyBean;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

@SpringBootTest
class ClientTracingServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private IClientTracingService iClientTracingService;

    @Autowired
    private IClientTracingRepository iClientTracingRepository;

    @SpyBean
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    private TracingMessage message;
    private final ArgumentCaptor<String> queueCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    private final ArgumentCaptor<TracingMessage> messageCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(TracingMessage.class);

    private static final Integer TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 60;
    private static final String REQUEST_QUEUE = "tracing.client.request";
    private static final String RESPONSE_QUEUE = "tracing.client.response";

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        message = new TracingMessage();
        message.setApiPath("/test/api");
        message.setHttpMethod("GET");
        message.setStatusCode("200");
        message.setRequestId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        message.setResponseId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        iClientTracingRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @DisplayName("Notify Tracing Message Request")
    @Test
    void whenNotifyJMSRequestMessage_thenQueueEqualsRequest() {
        message.setType(EMessageTopology.REQUEST);
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            iClientTracingService.notifyTracing(message);
        });
        try {
            future.get(TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            assertTrue(!future.isCompletedExceptionally());
            verify(jmsTemplate).convertAndSend(queueCaptor.capture(), messageCaptor.capture());
            assertEquals(REQUEST_QUEUE, queueCaptor.getValue(), "Queue not match: ".concat(queueCaptor.getValue()));
            assertEquals(message, messageCaptor.getValue(), "Original message was modified");
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            fail("Async execution failed or timed out");
        }
    }

    @DisplayName("Notify Tracing Message Response")
    @Test
    void whenNotifyJMSResponseMessage_thenQueueEqualsResponse() {
        message.setType(EMessageTopology.RESPONSE);
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            iClientTracingService.notifyTracing(message);
        });
        try {
            future.get(TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            assertTrue(!future.isCompletedExceptionally());
            verify(jmsTemplate).convertAndSend(queueCaptor.capture(), messageCaptor.capture());
            assertEquals(RESPONSE_QUEUE, queueCaptor.getValue(), "Queue not match: ".concat(queueCaptor.getValue()));
            assertEquals(message, messageCaptor.getValue(), "Original message was modified");
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            fail("Async execution failed or timed out");
        }
    }

    @DisplayName("Notify Tracing Message With Unknown Message Type")
    @Test
    void givenException_whenNotifyJMSUnknownMessageType_thenInvalidMessageTypeException() {
        message.setType(EMessageTopology.UNKNOWN);
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = iClientTracingService.notifyTracing(message);
        try {
            future.get(TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            fail("Expected InvalidTracingMessageTypeException, but no exception was thrown");
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            assertTrue(cause instanceof InvalidTracingMessageTypeException);
            InvalidTracingMessageTypeException exception = (InvalidTracingMessageTypeException) cause;
            assertEquals(EStep.TRACE_MESSAGE, exception.getStep());
            assertEquals(EErrorCodes.LOGICAL_ERROR, exception.getCode());
            assertThat(exception.getMessage()).contains("Invalid message type");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            fail("Timeout waiting for CompletableFuture to complete");
        }
    }

    @DisplayName("Notify Tracing Message With Null Message Type")
    @Test
    void givenException_whenNotifyJMSNullMessageType_thenInvalidMessageTypeException() {
        message.setType(null);
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = iClientTracingService.notifyTracing(message);
        try {
            future.get(TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            fail("Expected InvalidTracingMessageTypeException, but no exception was thrown");
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            assertTrue(cause instanceof InvalidTracingMessageTypeException);
            InvalidTracingMessageTypeException exception = (InvalidTracingMessageTypeException) cause;
            assertEquals(EStep.TRACE_MESSAGE, exception.getStep());
            assertEquals(EErrorCodes.LOGICAL_ERROR, exception.getCode());
            assertThat(exception.getMessage()).contains("Invalid message type");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            fail("Timeout waiting for CompletableFuture to complete");
        }
    }
}
```

## WHAT HAPPEN

1. When I run the single test it works
2. When I run all the tests they all work except **whenNotifyJMSResponseMessage_thenQueueEqualsResponse** because the **verify** method doesn't detect the code branch even if from the logs it runs

## LOGS

```
[2023-08-14 09:48:41,911] - [JmsClientTracing-1] - [INFO] - [] - [Notified message: 'TracingMessage(requestId=5ded9d50-aa41-4e9b-ba2d-eabb5125e470, responseId=6e1fa3a2-26f9-47c1-a42c-8d5b2a096830, statusCode=200, apiPath=/test/api, httpMethod=GET, type=REQUEST)']
[2023-08-14 09:48:41,913] - [JmsClientTracing-1] - [DEBUG] - [] - [Method: 'CompletableFuture com.tutorial.experiment.service.tracing.ClientTracingServiceImpl.notifyTracing(TracingMessage)' executed in 34ms]
[2023-08-14 09:48:41,914] - [Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@2db55dec)] - [INFO] - [] - [AMQ601265: User anonymous@invm:0 is creating a core consumer on target resource ServerSessionImpl() with parameters: [0, tracing.client.request, null, 0, false, true, null]]
[2023-08-14 09:48:41,922] - [JmsClientTracing-2] - [INFO] - [] - [Notified message: 'TracingMessage(requestId=690743d7-4a42-4d52-a10a-5d1be19211bb, responseId=f9a8feb8-a66e-44b4-9e82-3dbdd9b3c531, statusCode=200, apiPath=/test/api, httpMethod=GET, type=RESPONSE)']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test `whenNotifyJMSResponseMessage_thenQueueEqualsResponse()` performs two async actions and the test is just blocked for the first one.

1. The test is executed in the main thread (t1)
2. `runAsync` spawn another thread (t2) and  returns a `CompletableFuture` in t1
3. t1 gets blocked until t2 completes (`future.get()`).
4. In t2 the method under test is executed. The `@Async` annotation leads to another thread spawn (t3). Another `CompletableFuture` is returned to t2. This return value is ignored (it is not stored in any variable)
5. t1 is no longer blocked since t2 is completed.
6. The test resumes its work and might complete before or after BUT independent of t3
7. T3 completes at any time without notice to t1

The test `givenException_whenNotifyJMSUnknownMessageType_thenInvalidMessageTypeException`
calls the method under test directly.

I don‘t know why the test completes when executed in isolation. I have some favorites, but no evidences.